# Mixed use of Task and Dispatcher halts the task

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task, dispatcher

**Explanation**

I'm creating my own search control in WPF. This control is a `UserControl` that contains an area with search parameters (eg.: search on specific ID, name,...) and a `GridView` that shows the result.

In my control I have a `dependency property` of type `ICommand` where I bind the command to execute my search query.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SearchCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SearchControl));
```

Use of my control in a certain window:

```
 <customControls:SearchControl SearchCommand="{Binding SearchItemsCommand}"
                           SearchResult="{Binding SearchResult}" />
```

- `SearchItemsCommand` is a `Command` in my ViewModel where I can find my search query.
  In this command you can find my query to retrieve the result.
- `SearchResult` is my `ICollection` that contains the result of the search query.

**Code of the commands**

***Viewmodel***

```
 private DelegateCommand searchItemsCommand;
        public DelegateCommand SearchItemsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.searchItemsCommand== null)
                    this.searchItemsCommand= new DelegateCommand(this.SearchItemsCommandExecuted);

                return this.searchItemsCommand;
            }
        }

private ICollection<VoucherOverviewModel> voucherResults;
private void SearchItemsCommandExecuted()
        {
            using (DbContext context = new DbContext())
            {
                var query = (from v in context.Vouchers
                             join vt in context.VoucherTransactions on new
                                                                       {
                                                                           voucherID = v.VoucherID,
                                                                           type = VoucherTransactionType.Out
                                                                       } equals new
                                                                               {
                                                                                   voucherID = vt.VoucherID,
                                                                                   type = vt.Type
                                                                               }
                             join vtype in context.VoucherTypes on v.VoucherTypeID equals vtype.VoucherTypeID
                             join c in context.Customers on vt.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                             join pos in context.PointOfSales on v.PointOfSaleID equals pos.PointOfSaleID
                             select new VoucherOverviewModel()
                                    {
                                        PointOfSaleID = v.PointOfSaleID,
                                        PointOfSaleName = pos.Name,
                                        VoucherID = v.VoucherID,
                                        VoucherCode = v.Code,
                                        VoucherTypeID = v.VoucherTypeID,
                                        VoucherTypeDescription = vtype.Code,
                                        CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                                        CustomerName = c.Name,
                                        Value = vt.Value,
                                        UsedValue = context.VoucherTransactions
                                                           .Where(x => x.VoucherID == v.VoucherID &&
                                                               x.Type == VoucherTransactionType.In)
                                                           .Sum(x => x.Value),
                                        CreateDate = vt.Date,
                                        ValidFrom = v.ValidFrom,
                                        ValidUntil = v.ValidUntil,
                                        ParentVoucherID = v.ParentVoucherID,
                                        Comment = v.Comment,
                                    });

                foreach (ISearchParameter searchParameter in this.SearchParameters)
                {
                    if (!searchParameter.Value.IsNullOrDefault())
                    {
                        switch ((FilterVoucherParameterKey)searchParameter.Key)
                        {
                            case FilterVoucherParameterKey.CustomerID:
                                query = query.Where(x => x.CustomerID == (int)searchParameter.Value);
                                break;
                            case FilterVoucherParameterKey.VoucherID:
                                query = query.Where(x => x.VoucherCode.Contains((string)searchParameter.Value));
                                break;
                            case FilterVoucherParameterKey.PointOfSale:
                                query = query.Where(x => x.PointOfSaleID == (byte)searchParameter.Value);
                                break;
                            case FilterVoucherParameterKey.Type:
                                query = query.Where(x => x.VoucherTypeID == (byte)searchParameter.Value);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            this.voucherResults = query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

***Custom control***

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SearchCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SearchControl));

 public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICommand)this.GetValue(SearchCommandProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(SearchCommandProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

This is my dependency property so that I can bind the `SearchItemsCommand` to my Custom control.
Then I have another `ICommand` to execute the binded command and show the *loading element*  in my custom control. 
This `LocalSearchCommand` will be executed when you click on a button.

```
 private DelegateCommand localSearchCommand;
 public DelegateCommand LocalSearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.localSearchCommand == null)
                this.localSearchCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.LocalSearchCommandExecuted);

            return this.localSearchCommand;
        }
    }

    private void LocalSearchCommandExecuted()
    {
loadingElement.Visible = true;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                       {
                           this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.SearchCommand.Execute(null)));
                       })
                       .ContinueWith(t =>
                       {
                           if (t.IsCompleted)
                           {
                               t.Dispose();
                           }
                       });
    }
```

**The problem**

I want to show a *Loading element* when the query is executing to interact with the user. To show this element, I have to set it `visible`. 
The problem now is, when I set it visible and want to execute the search command, my whole UI freezes. After the result is fetched from the database and generated in the `GridView`, then, and only then, it shows my *loading element*. I do understand why this happens and I tried to solve it using a `Task`.

```
loadingElement.Visible = true;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                       {
                           this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.SearchCommand.Execute(null)));
                       })
                       .ContinueWith(t =>
                       {
                           if (t.IsCompleted)
                           {
                               t.Dispose();
                           }
                       });
```

I have to use the `Dispatcher` in my `Task` to execute the SearchCommand, because it is owned by the UI-thread. 
But because of the use of the `Dispatcher` class, I have the same problem as before. My *loading element*  is only shown when the query is already executed, because the `Dispatcher` executes the search command back on the UI-thread. 
Without the use of the `Dispatcher` class, it gives me the following error:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

I get this error on the line:

```
return (ICommand)this.GetValue(SearchCommandProperty);
```

**Even with an empty `SearchItemsCommandExecuted` method, the error occurs.**

**What I already tried**

- I tried setting the `TaskScheduler` of the `Task` to

  `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`
- I used a lot of combinations of `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke`.
- I tried to set the `Visibility` of the *loading element*  in the `Task`.

But none of the above did work.

How can I solve my problem, so that the *loading element* is shown when the query is executing. Did I miss something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Loetn

Comment: Why do you need your `SearchCommand` to be invoked in `Dispatcher` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Because it gives me the following error: `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.` With the `Dispatcher` it executes the command, without it gives me this error.

Comment: So, you need to post the code what you have in `SearchCommand`. That will be helpful.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel In my `SearchCommand` in my ViewModel, you can find the query (in LINQ) to retrieve the desired result. Nothing more. So I don't do anything there where I have to access the UI-thread. I think it has something to do with the `ICommand`.

Comment: No, Nothing is related to `ICommand`. If it is not confidential you can post the code. So that we can look into it? I guess it won't hurt you. The thing is either directly or indirectly you're accessing UI there.

Comment: Is that complete method? After assigning `query` what you do? I guess you set some property in VM which updates the UI via binding.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I updated it. I fetch the result and add it to a private `ICollection`. For now, I don't do anything with the result, but it already gave me that error.

Comment: Is that `voucherResults` type `ObservableCollection`? Does that bound to any UI element? answer depends on that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No, it bounds to nothing. Even with an empty `SearchItemsCommandExecuted` it generates that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the help of [this blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tamir/2007/04/29/dependency-property-getters-and-setters-in-multithreaded-environment/).

What I had to do is to edit the `getter` of my `Dependency property SearchCommand` so that it uses the `Dispatcher`.

```
public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICommand)this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                       System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                       (DispatcherOperationCallback)delegate { return this.GetValue(SearchCommandProperty); },
                       SearchCommandProperty);

               // Instead of this
               // return this.GetValue(SearchCommandProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(SearchCommandProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

And this is my `Command method`:

```
  private void LocalSearchCommandExecuted()
        {
            this.loadingElement.Visible = true;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                           {
                               this.SearchCommand.Execute(null);
                           })
                           .ContinueWith(t =>
                           {
                               if (t.IsCompleted)
                               {
                                   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.loadingElement.Visible= false));
                                   t.Dispose();
                               }
                           });
        }
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a new `Task` with a ThreadPool thread, but using `Dispatcher.Invoke`, which runs your command on the UI Thread, hence why your UI is freezing.

You need to offload your `SearchCommand` work to a background thread, then **update your UI with a Continuation** on the UI Thread (Dont try updating your UI inside `SearchCommand`):

then, it shows my loading element. I do understand why this happens and I tried to solve it using a Task.

```
loadingElement.Visible = true;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return this.SearchCommand.Execute(null);
})
.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    MyUIElement = t.Result; // Update your UI here.
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Who is `task`? In continuation task always is completed.

Comment: This does not work. To be complete, in the `Icommand` that I bind to `this.SearchCommand` I do nothing that involves the UI-thread. I just execute a query written with `LINQ`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov SearchCommand doesn't return anything. But I updated my question with some more code of my `Commands`. :)

Comment: You search your DB for that, but what do you do with it? I dont see it being returned anywhere? Why do you query your DB but do nothing with that data?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I fetch the result and add it to a private `ICollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Did not catch your binding of the first command to the second. So the following will proably not work. Looking into it...

EDIT 2: I assumed you want to start the background operation from your viewmodel. In the moment i can't think of another way than to make your loadingItem.Visible property a dependency property, move the background operation to your viewmodel, assign a property which is bound to loadingItem.Visible from there and remove the asynchronus stuff from your usercontrol.

You want to start your query on the background thread and assign the result to your ui thread:

```
    private void LocalSearchCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        //can also be your loadingItem. 
        VisibleElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //get the ui context
        var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //do your query on the background thread
            LongRunningOperation();
        })
                  //this happens on the ui thread because of the second parameter scheduler 
                               .ContinueWith(t =>
                               {

                                   if (t.IsCompleted)
                                   {
                                       VisibleElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                                       //assign the result from the LongRunningOperation to your ui list
                                       _list = new List<string>(_tempList);
                                       //if you need to...
                                       RaisePropertyChanged("SearchResults");
                                   }
                               }, scheduler );

    }

    private void LongRunningOperation()
    {
        //assign your result to a temporary collection
        //if you do not do that you will get an exception: An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source
        _tempList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            _tempList.Add("Test" + i);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```